# PreparedStatement select com like 'algo%' em Java Swing

Tags: java

como realizar a pesquisa `LIKE 'c%'` com `PreparedStatement`?
tenho o seguinte código:

```
PreparedStatement pstm;
ResultSet rs;

 public void pesquisarAdministrador(){
    String sql = "SELECT administrador.idadministrador, administrador.usr_adm FROM administrador WHERE usr_adm LIKE ?";
    try {
        pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstm.setString(1,"%" + txtId.getText() + "%'");
        rs = pstm.executeQuery();
        tblAdministrador.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    } catch (SQLException error) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, error);
    }           
}
```

porem ele não retorna nada, mas quando removo as tabelas e coloco `*` ele traz normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com sua outra pergunta, continuo achando que seu problema está no  like + case sensitive, então faria algo assim:

De

```
String sql = "SELECT administrador.idadministrador, administrador.usr_adm FROM administrador WHERE usr_adm LIKE ?";
```

Para

```
String sql = "SELECT administrador.idadministrador, administrador.usr_adm FROM administrador WHERE LOWER(usr_adm) LIKE ?";
```

E arrumar o parâmetro também:

De

```
pstm.setString(1,"%" + txtId.getText() + "%'");
```

Para

```
pstm.setString(1,"%" + txtId.getText().toString().toLowerCase() + "%");
```

#### Seu último `"%'"` possui uma aspas simples perdida, remova-a.

Comment: vacilo meu não era `txtId.getText()` e sim `txtbuscar.getText()`

Comment: @HebertdeLima hahaha, faz parte :)